# Google MAP API: How to draw shortest plane path between two geo-points?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to draw shortest plane path on a map. 
I created KML in Google Earth and loaded int to Google Map. As you can see attached images: paths is very different: Google Vap path is longer.
How to draw arc path on Google map?

[image: Path in Google Earth]
[image: Same path in Google Map]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In V3, it's simply adding the `geodesic: true` option to your Polyline.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/20/ Click on the map to define path endpoints

```
    var myLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      geodesic: true
    });

    var path = [];

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position:event.latLng});
      path.push(event.latLng);
      myLine.setPath(path);
    });
```

[image: result from demo]

Comment: Demo link expired.

Answer (score 0):

This example is for the API V2, but the math is the same for V3:
http://maps.forum.nu/gm_flight_path.html

Marcelo.