# How to get the shortest path between two points in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, shortest-path

I dont know if this is google's proprietary thing or its opensource. I need to know the way google does show the different routes and also the shortest of them based on **available roadway**. Because I have created an google maps app where user can put a marker and so get the simplest(shortest in my sense) to the destination with the available roads(not just the line as this Q shows ([Google MAP API: How to draw shortest plane path between two geo-points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959473/google-map-api-how-to-draw-shortest-plane-path-between-two-geo-points))

I know that this relates to Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path. but I was wondering if there is some library which I can use out-of-the-box.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to find the directions from one point to another?

This is provided in the google maps API.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService)